# Can't enter recovery mode after installing CWM 6.0.4.5 Advance Edition

Tags: recovery-mode

so I've been trying to update my galaxy S3 (T-Mobile) SGH-T999 to KitKat4.4 and after following a bunch of tutorials, I just installed CWM 6.0.4.5 Advance Edition on my phone. I used ODIN 3.09 to install philz_touch_6.12.8-i9500.tar.md5 (I know my phone is not a i9500, but one of the tutorials lead me to this file, could that be the problem?), followed all the instructions but now my phone won't go into recovery mode anymore.

Before all this I also rooted my phone (I used KingRoot) and tried ROM Manager, but after this didn't work I read that I needed to get the CWM 6.0.4.5 Advance Edition.

Anyone any idea what's going on or how I can fix this?

Thanks :)

EDIT: Just to describe what I mean by"won't go in recovery mode": When I press volume up, home and power button I get the SAMSUNG recovery screen, and then I let go of the power button and then nothing happens, black screen, phone is basically turned off. It turns on fine, but I just can't reach the recovery mode.

Comment: It is *heavily* discouraged to flash a package not *expressly* meant for a device. This is because even little differences in a model's hardware may result in software malfunctioning (if you're lucky - and you are -) or bricks. Your best choice would be to flash a recovery that's made for the **SGH-T999** and for it only.

Answer (score 0):

If the flashed recovery is correct then,

When you first time flash recovery then at the same boot you need to go in recovery mode
Otherwise your stock recovery will overwrite your recovery and you will not be able to go in your flashed recovery mode
Hope that helps

Comment: In that case, OP would still be able to boot into recovery (though ending up in the stock recovery). As per the description, that's not the case: "nothing happens, black screen, phone is basically turned off".

Comment: as you can read last two lines in EDIT: phone turns on fine but cant reach the recovery mode so thats why i had given that soln..:)

Comment: If the stock recovery had taken over, OP would have landed there then – not at an empty black screen :)

Comment: then must be flashed wrong recovery.:)

Comment: Exactly what has happened: the question itself indicates that, and our Salesman directly addressed it in his comment on the question. So no offense meant: you raised a very good point, but it's not an answer to the question. It would make a good comment, though: so as a mod, I'd offer to convert it to one (you need a little more rep to post comments, so you can't do that yourself). Agreed?